# Giving Horizontally Aligned Buttons A Fixed Position Within A Div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two buttons horizontally centered in them like this:

[image: div with buttons]

I want the buttons to have the same width from the bottom of the div regardless of the # of lines of text above them.

Normally I would give the parent div `position: relative;` and the buttons `position: absolute;`, however the absolute positioning in this case destroys their original alignment, causing the left one to completely fall off the page:

[image: div with missing buttons]

I don't know enough about CSS positioning to know why this is the case.

This is my existing html and css.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="formula-block centered" id="587d6b07c89e7613846a3cf3">
        <h4 class="padded-top"> Vegan Vit. D</h4>
        <p> fat soluble vitamin mix</p>
          <button class="button-success pure-button"><a href="/formula/587d6b07c89e7613846a3cf3">Show</a></button>
          <button class="button-warning pure-button">Delete</button>
    </div>
```

**CSS/LESS:**

```
.formula-block {
  height: 225px;
  width:  200px;
  border: 3px solid lighten(@dark-grey, 15%);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px @grey;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
a {
  color: @off-white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  }
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

How can I give the buttons a fixed distance from the bottom?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Position absolute is the right idea, One way to do it is to wrap both buttons in a div and position the div absolutely, instead of positioning each button absolutely.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vdbsa3fn/ there seems to be a number of styles not in your css.. also, it would appear both buttons are there, they are just covering one another.. try applying `left` and `right` properties to the appropriate button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  just need to give the left button `left: 0` and right button `right: 0`, where `0` is the position from the left or right you want them to be positioned. `0` can be a px value, em, %, etc, depending on your UI and how you want them to look.

```css
.formula-block {
  height: 225px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid lighten(@dark-grey, 15%);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px @grey;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  color: @off-white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5em;
}

.button-success {
  left: 0;
}

.button-warning {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="formula-block centered" id="587d6b07c89e7613846a3cf3">
  <h4 class="padded-top"> Vegan Vit. D</h4>
  <p> fat soluble vitamin mix</p>
  <button class="button-success pure-button"><a href="/formula/587d6b07c89e7613846a3cf3">Show</a></button>
  <button class="button-warning pure-button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can absolutely position a new element that wraps the buttons

```css
.formula-block {
  height: 225px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid lighten(@dark-grey, 15%);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px @grey;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  color: @off-white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="formula-block centered" id="587d6b07c89e7613846a3cf3">
  <h4 class="padded-top"> Vegan Vit. D</h4>
  <p> fat soluble vitamin mix</p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button-success pure-button"><a href="/formula/587d6b07c89e7613846a3cf3">Show</a></button>
    <button class="button-warning pure-button">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you.  Why does the absolute positioning cause one button to disappear behind the other?  It's a total mystery to me.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel you're welcome. Absolute positioning removes elements from the normal flow in the DOM, and relies on `top/left/right/bottom` based on a parent with `position: relative;` to position them. Without `top` or `bottom` CSS, the absolutely positioned element will be displayed with a `top` value of wherever it is on the page in relation to elements that come before it. Without `left` or `right` CSS, it will be displayed all the way to the left. And any elements that come after the absolutely positioned elements will overlap them since they no longer have layout on the page.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel so the 2 buttons overlap one another since neither had a left value and neither has layout on the page - they overlap all the way to the left (default place for an element to display) with the bottom value you specified. Hope that helps. It's kinda tricky.